# Proving that logistic regression on $I(X>c)$ by $X$ itself recovers decision boundary $c$ when $X$ is normal

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics

### Backgrounds

Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma^2)$, and define $C\equiv I(X>c)$ , for a given constant(**decision boundary**) $c$.

Now assume we perform a **logistic regression**:

$$\mathrm{logit}(P(C=1)) \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1X $$

Note that for **logistic regression**, the fitted $\displaystyle -\frac{\hat{\beta_0}}{\hat{\beta_1}}$ corresponds to the **mean** of underlying logistic distribution. (This is perfect separation case. Please also take a generous look at **imperfect separation case** at the bottom.)

---

### Problem

**My hypothesis says** the value should be the same, or at least similar as the criterion $c$, i.e.

$$
c \approx -\frac{\hat{\beta_0}}{\hat{\beta_1}} 
$$

I would like to **prove or reject the above argument**.

---

### Simulation

It is really hard to analytically derive the distribution of $\displaystyle -\frac{\hat{\beta_0}}{\hat{\beta_1}}$. Therefore with `R`, I simulated for various possible sets of $(\sigma, c)$ to test **my hypothesis**. Suppose we set, for instance,

- $\sigma: 5,10,15,20$
- $c : -5,4,12$

```
N = 1000
for(sig in c(5,10,15,20)){
  for (c in c(-5, 4, 12)){
    X = rnorm(N, sd=sig)
    C = (X > c)*1
    DATA = data.frame(x=X, c=C)
    coef = summary(glm(C ~ X, DATA, family = "binomial"))$coefficients
    print(sprintf("True c: %.2f, Estimated c: %.2f", c, -coef[1,1]/coef[2,1]))
  }
}
```

Note the **true $c$ and the estimated $-\hat{\beta_0}\big/\hat{\beta_1}$ are similar** as seen in the following output:

```
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.01"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 4.01"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 11.83"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.01"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 3.98"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 11.97"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.01"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 3.97"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 12.00"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.01"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 3.99"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 12.00"
```

**Note**: there were warning messages for nonconvergence!

---

### Try to prove

To compute maximum likelihood estimates(MLE), we have the log-likelihood to maximize:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} &= \mathrm{argmax}_{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} \mathrm{LogLik}(\beta_0, \beta_1) \\[8pt]
&\approx \mathrm{argmax}_{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} \mathbb{E}_X \mathrm{LogLik}(\beta_0, \beta_1) \\[8pt]
&= \mathrm{argmax}_{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} \mathbb{E}_X \left[ C\cdot(\beta_0 + \beta_1X) - \log[1 + \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X) \right] \\[8pt]
&= \mathrm{argmax}_{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} \mathbb{E}_X \left[ I(X > c) \cdot(\beta_0 + \beta_1X) - \log[1 + \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X) \right] \\[8pt]
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that

- $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}_X(I(X>c)) = P(X>c) = 1-\Phi(c/\sigma)$
- $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}_X(XI(X>c)) = \mathbb{E}_X \left(Trunc\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2,\min=c \right) = \sigma \frac{\phi(c/\sigma)}{1-\Phi(c/\sigma)}$ ([Wiki-Truncated Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution))

---

I'm currently finding $\mathbb{E}_X \log(1+\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X))$. However, I'm not sure if it is a valid approach. For instance if $\mathbb{E}_X$ is a linear function of $\beta_0,\beta_1$ then $\mathrm{argmax}_{(\beta_0, \beta_1)} \mathbb{E}_X$ may have no solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

### On imperfect separation

The following may obscure my main claim, but I would like to add this. As @Whuber noted I absurdly ignored the warning messages.

However, let us say the above is an idealized setting, and suppose there's a white noise in decision: say $C := I(X + W > c), X \perp W, W \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_W^2)$.

This may eschew some trivialities, but I see the similar tendency here: the recovery of $\displaystyle c \approx - \frac{\hat{\beta_0}}{\hat{\beta_1}}$, yet with some noise. I would really like to explain what caused this behavior.

```
N = 1000
for(sig in c(5,10,15,20)){
  for (c in c(-5, 4, 12)){
    X = rnorm(N, sd=sig)
    C = (X + rnorm(N, sd=5)  > c)*1
    DATA = data.frame(x=X, c=C)
    coef = summary(glm(C ~ X, DATA, family = "binomial"))$coefficients
    print(sprintf("True c: %.2f, Estimated c: %.2f", c, -coef[1,1]/coef[2,1]))
  }
}
```

Without warning messages,

```
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.35"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 4.31"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 12.27"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -4.91"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 3.87"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 11.93"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -4.72"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 3.73"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 12.25"
[1] "True c: -5.00, Estimated c: -5.16"
[1] "True c: 4.00, Estimated c: 4.25"
[1] "True c: 12.00, Estimated c: 12.41"
```

Comment: **Pay attention to the warning messages!**  Because your data are completely separated, the logistic regression solution for $\hat\beta_1$ diverges.  When you reparameterize the model as $E[\operatorname{Logit}(C)\mid X]=\alpha_0+\alpha_1(X-c),$ the solution is $\hat\alpha_0=0$ and $\hat\alpha_1\to\infty.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you a lot for your correct and considerate feedback. Would you mind if I ask you to take note at the edited version? Adding some white noise evaded warning messages, but replicated the behavior in question.

Comment: Thank you--that was a good way to fix up your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's lead off with a wonderful approximation.**  Here is a plot of two functions.

[image: Figure 1]

The underlying tan curve is the graph of $\Phi,$ the standard Normal CDF.  The overplotted blue curve is the graph of $\Lambda:z \to 1/(1 + \exp(-7z/4)),$ a scaled version of the logistic function.

To see how well they approximate each other, here is a plot of their difference $\Phi-\Lambda$ (over a wider range):

[image: Figure 2]

Their values never differ more than $\pm 0.015,$ less than one sixtieth of their full range (from $0$ to $1$).  That's close.  *It means you can use one or the other as the link in a logistic regression and it will make practically no difference.*

($\Lambda$ implements (up to a scale factor that will be absorbed in the coefficient estimates) the usual *logit* link while $\Phi$ implements the *probit* link.)

---

**Turn now to the question.**

With no loss of generality, choose units of measurement for $X$ that give it a unit variance.  To emphasize this, I will call this variable $Z,$ because it has a standard Normal distribution.  Let $\Phi$ be the cdf of the standard Normal distribution.

Adopting conventional notation, let $Y$ be the response given by thresholding a noisy version of $\beta_0 + \beta_ 1 Z$ at a value $t$ (for "threshold," instead of the less mnemonic $c$ in the question),

$$Y = \mathcal{I}\left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 Z + \sigma W \gt t\right)$$

where $W$ has a standard Normal distribution independently of $Z$ and $|\sigma|$ is the error standard deviation.  With the foregoing conventions, the question concerns the case $\beta_0=0$ and $\beta_1=1,$ but it will turn out there's nothing special about these choices: we will derive a universal result.

It is immediate that $Y$, conditional on $Z,$ has a Bernoulli$(p(Z))$ distribution with

$$\eqalign{
p(Z) &= \Pr(Y = 1) = \Pr(\beta_0+\beta_1 Z + \sigma W \gt t) \\
&= \Pr\left(W \gt \frac{t - (\beta_0+\beta_1 Z)}{\sigma}\right) \\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{-t + (\beta_0+\beta_1 Z)}{\sigma}\right).
}$$

**The trick is to approximate $\Phi$ by $\Lambda.$**  (Alternatively, perform your logistic regression using the probit link, which will give an exact result.)  Applying the logit (the inverse of $\Lambda$) to both sides of the foregoing equation produces

$$\operatorname{Logit}(p(Z)) \approx \frac{-t + (\beta_0+\beta_1 Z)}{4\sigma/7} = \frac{7(\beta_0-t)}{4\sigma} + \frac{7\beta_1}{4\sigma}Z.$$

**This is the (approximate) logistic regression for the model** (or, if you wish to think of it this way, of an entire population).  Therefore, **the logistic regression estimates from any sufficiently large random sample of this model must approximate its coefficients.**  (This is a well-known asymptotic property of the Maximum Likelihood procedure used to estimate those coefficients.)

Writing such estimated coefficients as $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1,$ we find that

$$-\frac{\hat\beta_0}{\hat\beta_1} \approx -\frac{7(\beta_0-t)/(4\sigma)}{7\beta_1/(4\sigma)} = \frac{t - \beta_0}{\beta_1}.$$

(It is now obvious that the potentially annoying factor of $7/4$ in the preliminary approximation is not a problem!)

In the question, $\beta_0=0$ and $\beta_1=1,$ giving

$$-\frac{\hat\beta_0}{\hat\beta_1} \approx t,$$

*QED.*

Answer (score 2):

Indipendently on the distribution of $X$, if $C$ is computed in that deterministic way, estimation won't converge because there is no couple of parameters $\beta$ for which likelihood is maximized.

It is easy to notice that $\hat c = -\frac{\hat \beta_0}{\hat \beta_1}$ maximises the likelihood at some middle value between last x value before $c$ and first one after it, but you have to keep $\beta_1$ fixed to observe this, and vary just $\beta_0$, because of the absence of one ML point for in the whole parametric space. I will make this clear now.

Let's say we take that value $\hat c$ fixed at the point we just described, for which likelihood is maximized for any given slope $\beta_1$, and we now vary $\beta_1$, to see how likelihood varies. Mind that $\beta_0$ will vary together with $\beta_1$ to keep $\hat c$ constant. We will notice that the higher the slope is, the higher the likelihood, without convergence. This always happens when logistic regression is used in a deterministic setting and no misclassifications happen.

I will add the mathematical details when I have time, but you can already verify my claims.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment. Aside from the perfect separation case, I would really address the behavior $\displaystyle c \approx - \frac{\hat{\beta_0}}{\hat{\beta_1}}$ even after I added some white noises.

Comment: In the perfect separation case, the estimate *will* converge provided you reparameterize the problem.  For instance, use $\theta_0=\beta_0$ and $\theta_1=1/\beta_1$ or $\beta_1=\tan(\theta_1).$  The MLE will converge to $\hat\theta_1=0$ (or, in the second option, to $\hat\theta_1=\pi/2$) and $\hat\beta_0$ can be any value that discriminates the $0$ responses from the $1$ responses.  In general, then, there are infinitely many solutions to the MLE rather than no solution.

Comment: well I guess it depends on what optimization method you are using, but usual Fisher scoring/Newton-Rampson shouldn't work for your reparametrizations. also, since $\frac{1}{0}$ is not actually a number, no method can reach that limit value precisely.

Comment: That's irrelevant here, because $1/0$ would arise only when $\beta_1$ is close to zero.  The tangent parameterization avoids that problem, anyway.

Comment: no, tangent function is not defined in $\pi/2$.

Comment: Work in the extended reals.

Answer (score 1):

One way to understand the solution to the problem - the answers by carlo, whuber and comments already say a lot of this - is to re-express the logit expression as $\exp(\beta_1 (\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))$, where $\gamma={\beta_0\over \beta_1}$. Doing so, you can maximize the likelihood

$$
\max_{\beta_1,\gamma} E\left [\mathbf{1}(X>c)\beta_1(\gamma+X)-\log[1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))] \right ]
$$

Taking first order conditions with respect to $\gamma$, you get:

$$
\beta_1 E\left[\mathbf{1}(X>c)-{\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))} \right ] = 0
$$

That is, conditional on the value for $\beta_1$, you'll set $\gamma$ so that the prediction errors of the logit function equal zero on average. For particular distributions of $X$ and values for $c$, the exact minimum will be $\gamma=c$. For other cases, this error minimization might choose different values for $\gamma$ as a way of minimizing the error for most observations.

Now, note that if $\beta_1\rightarrow \infty$,

$$
{\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
1\ &if\ \gamma+X>0\\
1/2\ &if\ \gamma+X=0\\
0\ &if\ \gamma+X<0
\end{cases}
$$

Then, if $\beta_1$ is picked to be high enough, the logit function will look very close to an indicator function stating that $X>-\gamma$. In such a case, the way to solve the first order condition for $\gamma$ when $\beta_1$ gets very high will be to set $\gamma\rightarrow -c$.

All I have leftover here is how the likelihood function solves for $\beta_1$. For this, the first order condition with respect to $\beta_1$ will be:

$$
E\left\{(\gamma+X)\left [\mathbf{1}(X>c)-{\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))} \right ] \right \} = 0
$$

Given that the term in square brackets has mean zero (from the first order condition with respect to $\gamma$), this FOC states that the "prediction error" from the logit function is uncorrelated with $\gamma+X$. Once again, if we let $\beta_1$ diverge to $\infty$, we can set the term in brackets to be arbitrarily close to zero, which will lead this expectation to be zero.

If you add white noise $W|X\sim F_W(W)$ that is independent of $X$, the first order conditions become

$$
\beta_1 E_X\left[1-F_W(c-X)-{\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))} \right ] = 0 \\
E_X\left\{(\gamma+X)\left [1-F_W(c-X)-{\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))\over 1+\exp(\beta_1(\gamma+X))} \right ] \right \} = 0
$$

Once again, the details of the approximation will depend on the distribution of $X$, the distribution of $W$ and the value of $c$. For $W\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, the logit function can be very similar to $1-F_W(c-X)$ for the right values of $\beta_1,\gamma$. For other thicker tailed functions $F_W$, or bi-modal functions $F_W$, results might become more sensitive to the values of $c$, distribution of $X$ and distribution of $W$.